# what is the php script for upload file which is sent from iphone sdk with help of NSURLSessionUploadTask class

Tags: php, iphone, web-services, upload, nsurlsession

I am creating an iphone application in which web service is being used. I am uploading the a file with the help of NSURLSessionUploadTask and NSURLSESSION class,but unable to get the sent file in server side using PHP language.

ios code

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"identifier"];

                self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

                NSURLSessionUploadTask *postDataTask = [_session uploadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request fromFile:(NSURL *)fileURL];
                [postDataTask resume];
```

But I have no idea that how can access this file in php side or which container of php contain this file data.
So please help me what do I write for php script for receive the file data

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try example given in following link.

http://cloudbings.com/questions/5592722/uploading-file-using-nsurlsessionuploadtask-to-php-server

I have same issue and I will try this solution and will share my feedback.